# FTP/SFTP client that can store sessions in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ftp, sftp

I'm looking for a FTP/SFTP client that can store all the session information in a central SQL server, so all employees always have an up-to date list of FTP sites they can connect to.
I've been using FileZilla in the past but it's lacking the multi-user capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use FileZilla with configuration files located on a network share, [as shown in this article](http://jonathanstegall.com/2008/05/26/sharing-a-filezilla-profile/).  Highlights:

- copy C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\docs\fzdefaults.xml.example to C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\
- edit the new C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\docs\fzdefaults.xml and point your config to your network location
- copy all files from C:\Users\username\appdata\Roaming\FileZilla (in Win7) to the network location
- sitemanager.xml in the network location should contain all your FTP servers

That should get you where you want to be.  You can use this cross-platform as well as detailed in the article.